# separate indexes on logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Currently I have logstash configuration that pushing data to redis, and elastic server that pulling the data using the default index 'logstash'. 
I've added another shipper  and I've successfully managed to move the data using the default index as well. My goal is to move and restore that data on a separate index, what is the best way to achieve it?

This is my current configuration using the default index:

shipper output:

```
output {
  redis {
    host => "my-host"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"
    codec => json
  }
}
```

elk input:

```
input {
        redis {
            host => "my-host"
            data_type => "list"
            key => "logstash"
            codec => json
          }
}
```

Comment: So... you want to use two separate Redis lists? Or are you talking about indexes in Elasticsearch? In the former case just have two `redis { ... }` blocks within your current `input { ... }`.

Comment: "My goal is to move and restore" -> are you talking about backup/restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the index filed in output. Give the name you want and then run that. so a seperate index will be created for that.

`input {
        redis {
            host => "my-host"
            data_type => "list"
            key => "logstash"
            codec => json
          }
}`

`output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
    index => "redis-logs"
    cluster => "cluster name"
  }
 }`

Comment: Thanks, i'ts working.i've added a rollover index. index => "redis-log"-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"